# Multiple columns with Foreign Key to the Same Table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a "MENU" TABLE that has the following fields

```
MENU_ID, MENU_NAME
```

I have a "USER" TABLE that has the following fields

```
USER_ID, EXPLORER_MENU_ID, TABLET_MENU_ID
```

EXPLORER_MENU_ID and TABLET_MENU_ID are FOREIGN keys TO MENU TABLE.
.
How can i get the following information FROM these two tables?

```
USER_ID, EXPLORER_MENU_NAME, TABLET_MENU_NAME
```

I have tried JOINs and Union and I can get this info in two different output records, one for EXPLORER_MENU_NAME and one for TABLET_MENU_NAME but I want this info in one single record as this

```
USER_ID, EXPLORER_MENU_NAME, TABLET_MENU_NAME
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is

```
select user_id, ( select menu_name from menu where menu_id = explorer_menu_id ) as explorer_menu_name,
( select menu_name from menu where menu_id = tablet_menu_id ) as tablet_menu_name
from user
```

Another can be using JOIN or LEFT JOIN. 
3rd one can be using WITH clause.

Comment: Thanks igr...this approach works just fine. I was also able to work out a solution using JOIN in the meantime but the plan of execution of your solution seems much better.